# PHP foreach is not looping through JSON file

Tags: php, json, loops, foreach

The `foreach` function is not running on this JSON file.

I would like the PHP to loop through the JSON file and output the data in an HTML table format.

```
<?php
// Store JSON data in a PHP variable
$url = 'https://eztv.io/api/get-torrents?limit=100&page=1'; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
//var_dump(json_decode($data));
$shows = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed and make an associative array
?>
<br /><br /><br /><br />

<table>
<?php
foreach ($shows as $shows) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <strong><?php echo $shows["title"] . "\n"; ?></strong>  </td>
        <td> <strong><?php echo $shows["season"] . "\n"; ?></strong>  </td>
        <td> <strong><?php echo $shows["episode"] . "\n"; ?></strong>  </td>
        <td> <a href="<?php echo $shows["magnet_url"] . "\n"; ?>">magnet</a></td>
        <td> <?php echo $shows["date_released_unix"] . "\n"; ?>  </td>
        <td> <?php echo $shows["size_bytes"] . "\n"; ?>  </td>
        <td> <a href="<?php echo $shows["episode_url"] . "\n"; ?>">episode Link</a></td>
        <td> <?php echo $shows["imdb_id"] . "\n"; ?>  </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
</table>
```

If I run this code I get a `Notice: Undefined index:` error on the page.

Comment: we do not know how the json string is

Comment: The link to the json is https://eztv.io/api/get-torrents?limit=100&page=1 or should i post it here ?

Comment: Do not use link, post the json file (if its huge post the part we need to read to help you)

Answer (score 1):

All the data at `torrents` key of response .
You should check the array index/key exist or not.

```
<?php 
$url = 'https://eztv.io/api/get-torrents?limit=100&page=1'; // path to your JSON file
$data = file_get_contents($url); // put the contents of the file into a variable
$shows = json_decode($data, true); // decode the JSON feed and make an associative array 
<?php foreach ($shows['torrents'] as $shows) : ?>
    <tr></tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
foreach ($shows as $shows) : ?>
    <tr>
        <td> <strong><?php echo $shows["title"] ?? '' . "\n"; ?></strong>  </td>
        <td> <strong><?php echo $shows["season"] ?? '' . "\n"; ?></strong>  </td>
        <td> <strong><?php echo $shows["episode"] ?? '' . "\n"; ?></strong>  </td>
        <td> <a href="<?php echo $shows["magnet_url"] ?? '' . "\n"; ?>">magnet</a></td>
        <td> <?php echo $shows["date_released_unix"] ?? '' . "\n"; ?>  </td>
        <td> <?php echo $shows["size_bytes"] ?? '' . "\n"; ?>  </td>
        <td> <a href="<?php echo $shows["episode_url"] ?? '' . "\n"; ?>">episode Link</a></td>
        <td> <?php echo $shows["imdb_id"] ?? '' . "\n"; ?>  </td>
    </tr>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Similar to Shivendra Singh's answer but instead we use a null coalescent just to make things easier to read.